# AngularJs or NodeJs or both

Tags: javascript, android, html, node.js, angularjs

I want to develop a website using JavaScript/HTML5/CSS3, because it is more flexible in UI. I read internet about AngularJS for the client side and about NODEJS: it can be used to both clent side and server side.
Can anyone kindly inform me about the cons and pros of the following:

- use AngularJs for client side and other language for server side (EX : PHP ).
- Use NODE.JS for build website
- or can I use both?

Comment: take a look a this: http://mean.io/#!/

Comment: @cuttlas Oh, they almost got me, but the ninja on front page... Marketing people, please stop overusing buzz words and images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for pros & consof Angular only, here is the list:

PROS

- Angular follows MV-Whatever architecture. Hence you can either MVP, MVC or MVVM.
- It gives the flexibility to do two way binding. Data binding tries to get rid of writing codes manually by relieving the backend server from creating templates. MVC pipeline is also maintained by the framework itself.
- DOM Manipulations at one place: You can make use of angular directives to play with the dom giving a neater code.There are some reusable tags defined by angular folks themselves in directives like ng-class, or ng-show. See [Angular Directive Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- Test Ready: The fact that AngularJS comes linked with Dependency Injection (DI) makes it ready for unit testing by injecting mock data into controller and measuring the output and behavior.
- Ionic Framework: Ionic Framework is written on top of Angular and is mainly used to build hybrid apps. So Angular is useful if you are going to extend your website into a mobile hybrid app.

Cons:

- Difficult to adapt the existing code: AngularJS requires the developer to re-implement the entire transformation code which makes it extremely hard to play around while adapting existing code.
- Heavy: Their are lighter frameworks like backbone and knockout, however seeing the power of Angular it can be easily negated

Now moving to your question whether Nodejs be used in conjunction to Angularjs my answer to it is:

**AWESOME COMBINATION**

You can have your server code residing in nodejs and use angularjs at client side keeping the architectures completely different. Since Nodejs also uses javascript there would be less of uptime for developers to learn it and start developing. Infact MEAN (Mongo-Express-Angular-Node) methodology. 
Their are various boilerplates available in order to kick start your development. One can be found at [MEAN](http://mean.io/#!/)

Comment: do You recommend to backonejs or MEAN.io

Comment: the question should be Backbone or Angular as both are client side framework. Well personally I would choose Angular as it is a framework which has lot of out of the box features and very little learning curve as compared to Backbone